# Modify CSS rule of inner tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, tags

I have something like this:

-HTML-

```
<table>
<tr class="x" onMouseOver="light(this)">
  <td>
    <a href="x">Link</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    Text
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

-CSS-

```
.x a{
  color: black;
}
```

-Javascript-

```
function light(x){
  x.style.color="red";
}
```

Now, the function works correctly, but my a tag doesn't changes his color. Is there a way to make Javascript modify the attribute color of the CSS rule .x a?

Comment: You can use the `:hover` pseudo-selector if you're just changing colors when people hover the links.

Comment: since your css is styling the `a` element directly, you would have to style use javascript to style the `a` element directly in order to override the css definition. It's part of its cascading nature.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be more suitable:

```
.x:hover {color:red}
.x:hover a{color:red}
```

This will override the link's colour when the row is hovered over, making the `onMouseOver` function unnecessary.

Note that it may fail in IE6, but personally I've never had any problems making things other than links `:hover` in that browser...

Comment: IE6 shouldn't even be mentioned anymore honestly. Just to point out however IE6 and below do not support pseudo class `:hover` on anything but a tags.

Comment: That makes compleltely useless the Javascript function and has a better effect! CSS's power. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
x.children[0].children[0].style.color="red";
```

You can define a `:hover` style in the CSS for the link too

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

That will change the links color when you hover over it (the link).

```
.x:hover a { }
```

will apply a style to the link when you hover over `.x`

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/q7jLB/)**

This will change all the links that are children to red.

```
function light(x){
  var elems = x.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i < elems.length;i++){
        elems[i].style.color="red";
    }
}​
```

Although I highly suggest using the `:hover` psuedo class like others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

-HTML- wrap your tr with in `<table>` tag, and convert to lowercase your `onmouseover` event attribute.

```
<table>
<tr class="x" onmouseover="light(this)">
  <td>
    <a href="x">Link</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    Text
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

-Javascript- change you javascript function body for select to `a` tag

```
function light(x){
  x.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].style.color="red";
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the <table> tags, I couldn't dare use <td> and <tr> outside a table