# Wordpress styles from customiser into stylesheet

Tags: wordpress

So I'm creating a WP theme and I have started building customisation for it, currently I have the styles go to the header and they are inline. Is there any way I can put them into a stylesheet after the options(get theme mod) have retrieved the information? Hope that makes sense. Or is it okay to have all the styles being inline in the header? It just seems really messy...

Thank you

Comment: Are the options universal, like a dark and a light theme, or do you give them options to change fonts, and colors per their choosing?

Comment: It's the options to change colours etc. Is that okay?

Comment: That's fine, just a little more work on your end. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic answer is : No, can not.

Because, the stylesheet is a css file, your `get_theme_mod()` or `get_option()` functions are wp core functions working in php script. Data is fetched through those functions and printed in header through `wp_head()`, the whole process is on the php files only.

> So, no wp core function can print it inside stylesheet.

Also, I have never seen any theme or plugin doing so. But if you are very interested a custom built function can be written using 3 php functions: `fopen()` `fwrite()` `fclose()`

That function will write desired string inside the stylesheet, but have to be parsed in `functions.php` or atleast before `<head></head>`

I think it is an fairly unique idea (some do this in custom template editors), subjected to views of other people.