# Is it possible to change css class properities through javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change css class properities through javascript?

Suppose I have class foo with width properity, by using javascript I want too update the widthof that foo class.

Before => .foo {width: 100px;}
After => .foo {width: 150px;}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript