# Add a StyleSheet in JS and allow it to be toggled dynamically

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to use JS to add a stylesheet to an HTML document:

```
// given CSS as text, add a <style> to the document
function addStyle(css) {
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
```

How do I create a checkbox that can toggle this (and only this) stylesheet on and off?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript/566445#566445) gives hints about how to manipulate stylesheets in JS, but there does not appear to be a way of *locating* a specific stylesheet without [looping through `document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheetList#Get_document_styleSheet_objects_with_for_loop) and matching against `document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].cssText`, which seems unwieldy.

Is there a better way to do this, *ideally without jQuery,* than a double loop?

(My particular use case is for a userscript (e.g. [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)), though I avoid [`GM_addStyle`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/index.php?title=GM_addStyle&oldid=6124) for portability.  All this really means is that I don't have direct control over the HTML; I'm modifying other sites.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In writing this question, I figured out the answer, **though it still leaves open the question of how to manipulate preexisting stylesheets** without too many loops.

Basically, while I can't use `getElementById()` or `querySelector()` to find a `style` element by its `id` attribute (because it's not in the `body`), I can save the object itself when I create it:

```
// given CSS as text, add a <style> to the document and return it
function addStyle(css) {
  var style = document.createElement("style");
  style.type = "text/css";
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  document.head.appendChild(style);
  return style;
}

var toggler = addStyle(`
  tr.informational { display:none; }
`);

// create and insert the toggling checkbox
var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.checked = true;
checkbox.onchange = function() { toggler.disabled = ! toggler.disabled };
var label = document.createElement("label"); // <label> allows clicking on text
label.appendChild(checkbox);
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hide informational rows"));

document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(label); // add to button panel
```

---

I had previously thought that Greasemonkey's security prevented accessing its objects after it finishes loading.  This would have meant the `checkbox.onchange()` line wouldn't work.  My original code was therefore quite ugly, finding `toggler_index` by looping over `document.styleSheets[]` to find my CSS and then constructing independent JS within JS by hard-coding that index:

```
checkbox.setAttribute("onchange", `
  var toggler = document.styleSheets[${toggler_index}];
  toggler.disabled = ! toggler.disabled;
`);
```

Thanks to StackOverflow for forcing me to question my assumptions when simplifying my question for posting here!