# change css file attribute values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the proper and fastest way to change CSS values using JavaScript?
For example, if I have a style.css file:

```
#h1 {
 color: 'red';
}
```

I need to change the color to any other color and update the CSS file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing CSS Values with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

```
document.querySelector('#h1').style.color = 'your-color';
```

Answer (score 3):

**JS:**

```
document.getElementById("elementsId").style.color= "red";
```

My recommendation would be not to use Id name like `h1` as it may be confusing with the `<h1>` tag in html. Use more clear variable name like `headerId`.

for changing multiple css properties use this:

```
document.getElementById(elementsId).setAttribute("style","wi‌​dth: 500px; background-color: yellow;");
```

Comment: but this will only change the color at that moment. I want to change the css file value also.

Comment: @DilakshanSooriyanathan, you can not update the css file values with javascript however you can change multiple css properties like this `document.getElementById(elementsId).setAttribute("style","width: 500px; background-color: yellow;");` or you can write a class in css in advance and add that class to your element when needed using Js as pointed by prashant

Comment: You cannot change the css file, CSS is not dynamic. The best you could do is use some kind of preprocessor (Saas/Less), regenerate a CSS file and unload the previous one and load a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3):

for multiple css property change use with `classname` add .it reduce the code lines in dom

```
document.querySelector('#h1').classList.add('your-class')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('h1').css('color','#ff5722');
```

```css
#h1 {
 color: 'red';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1> this color tho</h1>
```

Jquery is from javascript so once you learn jquery you will sometimes go back to javascript