# Edit inline styling with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is there a way to change this inline styling with javascript?

```
element.style {
    background-color: rgb(125, 210, 195);
}
```

I can't seem to find the origin of the code in my theme files.

This is the raw html:

```
<span class="qodef-post-image-overlay" style="background-color: rgb(125, 210, 195);"></span>
```

Comment: can you give more code context?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do, but you may want to look into media queries and/or pointer-events. As long as you're not getting too crazy you can probably achieve whatever you're trying to do without JavaScript.

Comment: Question is not clear at all. Not clear if you are trying to override that inline style or add it or why you can't use css. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing CSS Values with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript)

Comment: I've added some more context, is it clear now?

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript**: Use [HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property:

> The `HTMLElement.style` property is used to get as well as set the inline style of an element.

Please notice the camel case use of property name.

```
element.style.backgroundColor= "rgb(125, 210, 195)";
```

```js
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor= "rgb(125, 210, 195)";
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">Test</div>
```

**jQuery**: Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

> Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.

```js
$('#myDiv').css({"background-color":"rgb(125, 210, 195)"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery:

`$(element).css("background-color", "rgb(125, 210, 195)");`

Answer (score 1):

easy with jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.element').css('background-color','rgb(250,100, 100)');
});
```

```css
.element {
    background-color: rgb(125, 210, 195);
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```